# Session cookies are not always sent to server in Android Webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, cookies, chromium, webviewchromium

I am working on an ionic app using the [in-app-browser](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins) plugin to open an embedded **webview**.

The URL displayed in the webview replies with a "set-cookie" to start a new session, and redirects to a new url that loads the app. All this works fine.

The app loads ressources (js, images) and make XHR calls, which sends the session cookie just fine. At some point, randomly, the **browser will stop sending the session cookie** for one of the resources. It is not always the same resources, and it doesn't always happen.

In the example below, a request to load a favicon is sent with the cookie (OK). The next request doesn't send the cookie. As a result, the server will create a new session and set a new cookie.

First request:
[image]

Second request, no session cookie sent:
[image]

**Why does the browser stop sending the session cookie?**

Is it because of the existing JSESSIONID cookie for another subdomain? But it already exists on the first request.

Is it linked to the "Session" expiry? I tried setting the JSESSIONID cookie **max-age** with no success.

I am also aware of the "[Lax+POST](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/faq/#q-what-is-the-lax-post-mitigation)" fix in chrome, but this is a GET request.

Note that I haven't observed the issue on iOS safari (but as it is random, I am not 100% sure it doesn't exist).

Comment: I am having the same problem, which occurs only in SDK 32 and 33. How were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: I could not solve it. In the end, I have just used another mechanism for authentication based on tokens instead of cookies. I also have stopped using the plugin https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins and now use https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser

Comment: Thanks for answer... Since cookiesyncmanager is deprecated, I replaced it with cookieManager and I think this is the main reason it happens.